# vsftpd FTP server on Linux

Tags: permissions, vsftpd

I just installed this FTP server and it works fine. I noticed that the FTP user can read an write their own directory but they can read and download other files also (owned by other users or by system). Can I disallow this behavior?
Many thanks

This is my /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
   listen=NO
   listen_ipv6=YES
   anonymous_enable=NO
   local_enable=YES
   write_enable=YES
   dirmessage_enable=YES
   use_localtime=YES
   xferlog_enable=YES
   connect_from_port_20=YES
   chroot_local_user=YES
   secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
   pam_service_name=vsftpd
   rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
   rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
   ssl_enable=YES
   user_sub_token=$USER
   local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
   pasv_min_port=30000
   pasv_max_port=31000
```

Comment: What do you mean by "owned by other users"? User? Group? Permissions? Path?

Comment: I mean everything: example.
Using Filezilla and accessing by the "newftpuser" user created for vsftpd testing I can grab files from: /usr/local/bin, /sys/kernel, /home/pi and so on... all owned by "pi" and "root" users. Should not be as this and I should also not access the contents of directories not belonging to "newftpuser"

Comment: You're connecting to this with an IPv4 address or an IPv6 address?

Comment: with IPv4, via LAN